# Alignment issue in the grid with locked columns

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1.

I have a grid with paging. The first few columns in the gird is locked. And since the resutl set is big (lot of columns), I get horizontal scroll bar. And this is how it looks:
The scroll bar only starts after the locked columns (which makes sense as the first columns as locked).

![Paging_One][1]

The problem: 
Since the last record is always under the scroll bar, user is not able to see it. Also, if user uses down key to navigate to it, the alignment goes off and it looks ugly. See the below image to see the alignment issue.
![enter image description here][2]

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling: treeGrid.getView().refresh()

After you call treeGrid.show()